# Really, really, really hard sequence

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, enigmatic-puzzle, number-sequence

... in which you have nothing to do with math
... except maybe with some counting and this and that
... but no calculations, no, definitely no.

> $1, 0, 8, 62, 90, 68, 83, 89, 88, 057, 619, 028, 693, 069, 068, 985, 086, 988, 871, 820, 838, 865, 890, 868, 887, ?, ?, ?, ...$

**Question:**

> What are the next elements?

**Hint 1:**

> 4 is missing for reasons.

**Hint 2:**

> 4 is too much.

**Hint 3:**

> 4 is somehow ambiguous.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The next numbers are:

> $889, 888, 0123$

Because

> they are ternary representations of the natural numbers starting at $0$, where the trits are the number of holes in the base $10$ digits
>  The next ternary numbers to represent are $221, 222, 1000$.
>  You are cycling through $(0,6,9)$ for those with one hole,
>  through $(1,2,3,5,7)$ for those with no holes,
>  with just $8$ for two holes.
>
>  $4$ has a hole so it could be used but you decided not to do so because it may also be written without one
>  ($0$ *could* be written with a slash through it too, giving it two holes).

Comment: Well... half way done. Probably because of my fault with exchanged elements (sorry for that). Answer is unambiguous, so... Well done so far :)

Comment: @kamenf I updated it to use the rest of the methodology I believe

Comment: Now it is perfect. And about 0... well, when I was at school there was no such thing as slashed zero, so I totally forgot that case :-D

Comment: Yeah, it does not matter really, just thought I'd pop that in there - you are writing the numbers after all :)

Comment: Yes, but it is worth mention it :)

Comment: I can't help but wonder how ternary to decimal conversions aren't "calculations", but maybe that's just me

Comment: @warspyking I don't think any conversion (ether from ternary to decimal or vice-versa) is needed to solve this puzzle. Even to present them as text. Just digits. :)

Comment: I  write 2s with holes... :(