# Number trouble in here

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, number-sequence

I have been given 24 hours to solve this.

> So, my friend has given me 10 examples.
>
> $$1024 = 1$$
>
> $$1000 = 3$$
>
> $$2880 = 5$$
>
> $$6591 = 2$$
>
> $$2113 = 0$$
>
> $$1345 = 0$$
>
> $$1987 = 3$$
>
> $$8888 = 8$$
>
> $$5632 = 1$$
>
> $$6124 = 1$$

So, the question is

> $$ 2456=?$$

Comment: Okk, I didn't know that this was already posted beforehand... I would delete it. Sorry for any inconvenience..

Comment: No need to delete it. Nothing wrong with leaving a dupe here.

Comment: You could now ask your friend to solve a variation of a [similar puzzle I posted](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/32382/16717) :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yeah... maybe I should give him a month time for that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> 1

Reason:

> the result is the number of round holes in the digits.
>
>   0 - one hole, 1 - zero holes, 2 - zero holes, 3 - zero holes, 4 - zero, 5 - zero, 6 - one hole, 7 - zero, 8 - two holes, 9 - one hole.